# Purple line of Samsung galaxy s7

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7, physical-damage

I have a Samsung galaxy s7 in gold. It has been stepped on. Now, there is purple bleeding on the left side with a few pale purple around the screen. I can’t enter my phone because I has a pattern passcode. I won’t let me touch the left area. I think the internal has been damaged but I am not sure. I can’t go and fix it during a pandemic. Can I be helped?

Comment: If you have an OTG cable/adapter and a mouse lying around or if you can manage to get a hold of them (a friend, online delivery, etc.), you should be able to unlock your phone using a mouse and also operate it at least for making some online backups.